# Call to WPF window inside new project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have crated WPF project that are working well.
now I need to copy this to **existent solution ,under specific project in a new folder.**
(I copy all to the new folder ).
now I want to test it(the WPF),how can I create program or anything else which can help me to invoke the WPF main window etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of the target project (class library, WPF application...)?

Comment: @DamirArh- its class libarary

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly start a class library, therefore you'll need another project (probably WPF application) as the startup project.

Inside it reference your class library (let's say it's called `ClassLibrary1`) and delete the default `MainWindow.xaml` that comes with the project template.

Now you only need to change the `StartupUri` property in `App.xaml`. You'll need to use the pack syntax:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/Windows/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources />
</Application>
```

In the above example, I assumed your WPF window is named `MainWindow` and placed in a `Windows` folder. You can read more about the pack syntax [here](http://aspotofc.blogspot.com/2008/09/specifying-alternate-assembly-for.html).